# Calculate a number to the power of a large integer

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to help someone calculate the value of 4^3e9.

The problem is that most software don't support numbers this large. Is there an alternative way to calculate this?

My first attempt is to try to divide the number as it is being calculated by looping from 1 to 3e9. If the intermediate result is > 10 then I divide it by it's power of 10, then add this to a variable. In the end I will have a floating point number and the power of 10.

```
import math
powerof10 = 0
powerof = int(3e9)
# print('powerof', powerof)
initial_value = 4
float_value = initial_value
for i in range(1,powerof): #start from 1 to get correct number of operations
    float_value *= initial_value
    # print('float value', float_value)
    print(i)
    if (float_value > 10):
        powerof10increment = math.floor(math.log10(float_value))
        # print('powerof10', powerof10increment)
        powerof10 += powerof10increment
        float_value /= 10**powerof10increment
        # print('reduced float value', float_value)
print(float_value, ' x 10^', powerof10)
```

This based on this question here: [I want to know what is the value of 4 to the power of 3000000000 (3e+9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348758/i-want-to-know-what-is-the-value-of-4-to-the-power-of-3000000000-3e9)

According to the question the number should be in the format 1 x 10^x, so I think only x is required.

Comment: Do you really need to calculate the full number, or do you need to figure out the last few digits of that number?

Comment: There's a fast way to approximate `powerof10` in the above code: `log(10, 4**x)` is equal to `x*log(4)/log(10)`, so `powerof10 = (3e9)*log(4)/log(10)`. Is that accurate enough for your purposes?

Comment: I bet no numeric variable can hold the final result that big. How are you going to present that?
4^3e9 = 2^6e9 so the binary string representation is 1 followed by 6e9 zeros.

Comment: @NickODell I think it should be, I've added a link to the original question which was closed.

Comment: It has almost 2 billion decimal digits in it. So the next question is very important: what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: @SiuPangTommyChoi: I was able to calculate it just fine on my computer, a standard laptop.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it's for someone who needs help but didn't get it. Not for me personally

Comment: @BrendanOtherwhyz get them to post, because understanding why anyone _actually_ needs this matters =)

Comment: I linked to the closed question in the question description. The user did already, twice. But their question was closed both times, and they are a new user. I linked this question to a comment in their question but I don't know if they have seen it. I don't know them but I thought what happened was unfair and I though I could make stackoverflow seem less intimidating and supportive in the process. There's no way to mention a user with no activity in this question, or message a user directly is there?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @[NickODell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell) for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393424/calculate-a-number-to-the-power-of-a-large-integer#comment133030948_75393424)!

```
import math
powerof10 = (3e9)*math.log(4)/math.log(10)
print(powerof10)
significand = 10**(powerof10 - math.floor(powerof10))
print(significand, 'x 10^', math.floor(powerof10))
# 9.63578180503111 x 10^ 1806179973
```

Which matches with the [result I get from Wolfram Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taYR6.png).

Comment: If an approximate answer in scientific form is what you're after, you could just use the `decimal` module. After doing `getcontext().Emax = 10**10`, `print(Decimal(4)**Decimal('3e9'))` gives me `9.635786555620803001764714994E+1806179973`